# Как выделяется и удаляется при вызове return

Tags: c++, память, return, выделение-памяти

Как выделяется память под выражения : `return c+sum(2,7)` и `return(a+b)`
И когда происходит очистка выделенной памяти?

```
int sum(int a, int b){
    return(a+b);
}
int main(){
    int c=5;
    return (c+sum(2,7));
}
```

Comment: Да какая память? В реальности значение будет возвращено в регистре процессора, в теории — в стеке выделяется место для возвращаемого значения, которое благополучно чистится путем изменения указателя стека после вызова...

Comment: В более общем случае компилятор вставляет инструкции для стека и вызовы деструкторов. Если конечно не пытаться обмануть компилятор.

Answer (score 2):

Так как вы возвращаете *временный* объект, срок действия этого объекта заканчивается после окончания выражения, содержащую данную функцию.

```
int z = sum(sum(1,2)/* А */ , sum(3,4)/* Б */)/* В */;
```

Возвращаемые значения `А` ,`Б` и `В` имеют рабочую область жизни при сложении друг друга, и при присваивании результата переменной `z`. Заканчивается после точки с запятой (*окончании выражения*).

При конце жизни этих временных объектов происходит вызов их деструкторов. Они имеют область хранения автоматическими, а это значит, что в зависимости от настроек компилятора они могут храниться в регистрах или в стеке или на усмотрение архитектуры. Так как в вашем примере объекты очень простые типа `int`, то они могут не иметь место в памяти, а будут храниться только в регистрах процессора. Деструктора у типа `int` нет.